# Undefined control sequence using pdfx and Lualatex

Tags: luatex, pdfx

Compiling a simple example on PDF/A with Lualatex returns the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.660  \ifnum\shellescape
```

Or, for a PDF/X:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.333  \pdfobjcompresslevel
                         =0 \relax
```

How can I compile a document under Lualatex with PDFx compliance?

Example code, running on Texlive 2018:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[x-4]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Intro}
Things and stuff.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `pdfx` requires `luatex85`. It is only required for Luatex, so they don't get pulled in by the package manager. Installing `texlive-luatex85` fixes the problem. No need to modify the tex.

(The documentation claims `pdftexcmds` from `texlive-oberdiek` can also be used, but it doesn't work on my box, I need `luatex85` or both.)